# How do I parse the attached XML code using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a requirement to read data from the XML file.
Here is the data in XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<application id="AndroidCoverFlow" name="AndroidCoverFlow" platform="general">
       <attributes datatype="ref" value="{"coverflowConfig":{"spaceBetweenRowItems":5,"projectionAngle":90,"isCircular":true,"rowItemWidth":5,"rowItemRotationAngle":180}}" name="viewConfig" platform="general" buckettype="basic"/>
       </application>
```

in the specified example, I want to verify/Read the coverflowconfig values.i.e 
spaceBetweenRowItems,
projectionAngle
projectionAngle.

Comment: This isn't valid XML.  You have double quotes inside double quotes in your `value`.  Is this what it *really* looks like?

Comment: It looks like you have JSON in your XML...

Comment: Are u shure is it:  value="{" and not:  value="{'

Comment: I am sure,the attached snippet is correct  one.This is generated from some javascript code through IDE.i have copied some content from the whole xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this isn't the *exact* XML, because it's not valid.  But forgetting that... assuming it *is* valid, you can parse it using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Parsing_and_serializing_XML).

```
var parser = new DOMParser,
    xmlDom = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');

var application = xmlDom.getElementById('AndroidCoverFlow'),
    attributes = application.getElementsByTagName('attributes');

var value = attributes[0].attributes.getNamedItem('value').value,
    jsonData = JSON.parse(value);

console.dir(jsonData);
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/soxobuba/2/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/MUws7/

**NOTE:**

> It is not an XML code, You could check it By :
>   http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

However , if it is an XML Code , You can use a Javascript library such as jQuery, then  do this :

```
$(xml).find("attributes").each(function()
  {
   var myObject=$(this).attr("value")
   $("#output").html(myObject);
       myObject=myObject.replaceAll("'",'"')
      alert(myObject)
      coverflowConfig=$.parseJSON(myObject).coverflowConfig;
      alert('coverflowConfig.projectionAngle='+coverflowConfig.projectionAngle)


  });
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/MUws7/

Comment: The question doesn't say that he's using jQuery.

Comment: jquery = is a JS library

Comment: Yeah.  I'm *well* aware what jQuery is.  The person asking the question the didn't indicate that they are using it.  So, you might wanna mention that this uses the jQuery library in your answer.